# how to run SpringBoot App with dependency `spring-boot-docker-compose` locally outside of docker?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Using the website https://start.spring.io / I have created a new spring boot project.

I am add to dependencies 'Docker Compose Support'
[image: Docker Compose Support from start.spring.io]

Now, when I try to run the application locally, I get an error that docker was not found. But I don't want to run the application locally in docker during development. On debian, where docker is installed, the application runs without problems, but how do I run it locally OUTSIDE of docker?
[image: Run from IDEA on remote(virtual box) Debian]

The main reason is that every time you change the application, you need to recreate the image, which is wildly inconvenient.

I've been working with docker since yesterday.

[image: IDEA Run configuration]
[image: IDea run configuration local machine]
[image: Unable to start docker process. Is docker correctly installed?]

application.yaml:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  devtools:
    add-properties: false
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

logging:
  file:
    name: './logs/app-backend.log'
  level:
    com.prototype.app: INFO
  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
      file-name-pattern: './logs/archived/app-backend-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz'
      max-file-size: 10MB
      total-size-cap: 1GB
      max-history: 60
```

[image: app configs structure]

Dockerfile:

```
# Build stage
FROM gradle:8.3.0-jdk20 AS BUILD
WORKDIR /usr/app/
COPY . .
RUN gradle clean build -x test

# Package stage
FROM eclipse-temurin:20.0.2_9-jdk
ENV JAR_NAME=app-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY --from=BUILD $APP_HOME .
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar $APP_HOME/build/libs/$JAR_NAME --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  app:
    image: 'docker-spring-boot-postgres:latest'
    container_name: 'app'
    build:
      context: '.'
    depends_on:
      'postgres-db':
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - 'postgres-db:/data/postgres'
    environment:
      - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-db:5432/mydatabase'
      - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=myuser'
      - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=secret'
      - 'SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=validate'
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    networks:
      - 'postgres-db'
    restart: 'always'

  postgres-db:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    container_name: 'postgres-db'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=mydatabase'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret'
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=myuser'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres-db:/data/postgres'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - 'postgres-db'
    restart: 'unless-stopped'
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U myuser -d mydatabase
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3

networks:
  postgres-db:
    driver: 'bridge'

volumes:
  postgres-db:
```

If you notice obvious errors in the docker configuration, please report it, I have configured this for the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot's Docker Compose integration requires Docker to run the containers listed in your `compose.yaml` file. Your app should not be one of those services. The services should be only the things upon which your app depends. In your case that would appear to just be Postgres.

To use the Docker Compose integration, you start your application by running its main method in your IDE. As part of starting up, Spring Boot will then call `docker compose up` to ensure that the services upon which it depends are available.

If you don't have Docker installed then you can't use Docker Compose and, therefore, can't use Spring Boot's Docker Compose integration. You can either remove the `spring-boot-docker-compose` dependency from your app or set `spring.docker.compose.enabled` to disable it.

Comment: What if I have no service defined yet in compose.yaml? For me, app fails ot start?